# Get index when deep watching a collection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$scope.$watch('myData', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
        console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
        //do something
    }, true);
```

It executes fine when I update a property inside the myData collection but in the newValue and oldValue I get the collection. Is there a way to get the index of the item changed?

Answer (score 0):

What if the `$watch` gets triggered because all the items of your collection have been removed? What index would you want to get in that case?

Or what if it gets triggered as a result of a `splice` that it's removing some items and adding some other items in the same operation?

Or what if it gets triggered because more than one item of the collection has changed?

What I'm trying to explain is that when you have a deep `$watch` on an array of objects, the `$watch` can be triggered for many different reasons, in your question it seems that you are assuming that the `watch` will be triggered because one item has changed, and that is not necessarily true, many other things could have changed.

You can use the newValue and the oldValue that get provided to you in the parameters of the `$watch` function in order to figure out the changes that have occurred, in that way if the change is that one of the items has changed you will be able to find which one it was and what its index is.